# set a global variable at runtime

Tags: fortran

is there a way in fortran to set a global variable at runtime?

My program should read a model-file containing a parameter 
if the simulation should be in 2d or 3d.
So it must read that variable from file and than set this parameter.

Is this possible?

Thank you,
Jan

Comment: Yes, what you seek to do is possible. Not, mind you, without code.  I'm voting to close this on the grounds that, without code, this is not an answerable question.  And do note that in Fortran the value of a `parameter` is set at compile time, it can't be read and set at run-time.  Be careful with your use of terminology.  Post some code before another 4 readers pile in with close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have a variable set to a default (lets say 2d) then after Reading the faile change it's value as appropriate? depending on your requirements you could even have it have other values.

for exemple, have a global integer value set to 0. Then after file read, change it to 1 (2d) or 2 (3d). That way you have:

```
0 => not set yet (waiting for model-file)
1 => simulation should be in 2D
2 => simulation should be in 3D
3 => there was an error Reading the model-file
```